# Laravel 5.4 'Route' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' > Error

Tags: php, syntax-error, laravel-5.4

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error.

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Route' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'
in web.php (line 61)
```

[Route screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwAbB.png)
I didn't found any script error in my code. If anyone would help, that will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forgot to close your route groups, add `);` after curly brackets

Comment: Can you specify the line ? or some word from any route list.

Comment: on line 59, 76 and may be more

Comment: See the screenshot again 59 has closing bracket. also 76 has.

Comment: you given only closing curly braces, add `);` after it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your groups you're writing

```
->group(function(){
   //whatever
}
```

forgetting to close the group(),

For example on line 59 replace } with });

Turning it to

```
->group(function(){
   //whatever
});
```

Comment: @SyedBakibillahSakib the same thing i said to you in comment

Comment: Yeah I see that now sorry. and thanks again Raushan Kumar.